# How much is Complement de Parcours?

Tags: transportation, paris, cdg

I am going to be travelling into Paris. I land in CDG but am not sure of how to get to Paris (Gare du Nord). I am planning to buy a Navigo Decouverte with zones 1-2 loaded on. I also am travelling to Versailles and back. I have heard about Complement de Parcours and have seen that they give discounts on tickets. I am travelling in a group of four (me included) and I was wondering if I am better off getting the ND with zones 1-2 or zones 1-5?

What is the cheaper option, a Navigo Découverte zone 1-2 plus a complément de parcours to Versailles, or a Navigo Découverte zone 1-5?

Comment: Do you want to consider the trip from the airport as well? Will you fly out of CDG or only land there? How long are you staying? I provided an answer for Versailles assuming you would buy a Navigo for a week and some links that might help you figure out other scenarios but airport fares seem more complicated. In particular, I think complément de parcours is not possible on buses so you would need to pay the full fare on RoissyBus.

Comment: Thread on the trip from the airport on another site: http://www.tripadvisor.com/ShowTopic-g187147-i14-k6509893-Complement_de_parcours_to_supplement_navigo_decouverte-Paris_Ile_de_France.html

Answer (score 3):

To go to Versailles-Château-Rive-Gauche from the center, you only need zones 1-4. A Navigo semaine for zones 1-4 is 32 € or 11.60 € more than a zones 1-2 pass. According to [the map on Wikipedia](http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/b/b4/RER_C.svg), the last station in zone 2 on RER C trains to Versailles is Issy-Val-de-Seine.

A “origine-destination” ticket from this station to the Château costs 1.80 € and this should also be the price of a “complément de parcours” if you have a Navigo for zones 1-2. A round trip would therefore cost you 3.60 €. Even twice the full fare from the center (3.35 € times two so 6.70 €) is still under the difference between the Navigo semaine zones 1-2 and 1-4 prices.

Sources used:

- [Navigo prices](http://www.transilien.com/static/tarifs/forfait-navigo-semaine-mois) on transilien.com
- [Fare finder](http://www.transilien.com/tarif/tarif/init) on transilien.com
- [How “complément de parcours” prices are computed](http://www.ratp.fr/fr/ratp/r_84552/complement-de-parcours/) on ratp.fr